# ReInstall fail on Android

Tags: android, certificate, apk, publishing

I have made a new version of my app and wanted to distribute it, but if there is an old version of the application on the device, the new version of the app does not allow to install with this error: "install failed inconsistent certificates." How do I manage to reinstall operation? Our customers dont want to uninstall before the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign the new apk with the same certificate you used signing the old one. Otherwise you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mdk version and while creating application, it ask for the android version, check if they both th apps are having same version, if they are different , error occurs......

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign a new build with same keystore file which you used to signed a previous build.